# Erro 505 ao instalar App do Google Play no Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-permission

Sou desenvolvedor e estou com problemas para instalar um app na versão Lollipop.

Dei uma pesquisada e acredito que seja erro de duplicidade de *packages*, ou seja tem dois Apps chamando o mesmo pacote (mas não tenho certeza), este faz parte do meu código. Os dois app tem a mesma permissão: `android:name="br.exemplogcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE`.

```
<permission
    android:name="br.exemplogcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="br.exemplogcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Eu tenho dois apps, e os dois usam o pacote **br.exemplogcm**. Será que é isto que está dando erro? Eu não tenho a versão Lollipop, então fica difícil fazer testes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De fato, você não pode ter dois aplicativos que fazem requisição de uma mesma permissão assinada.

Você pode conferir no seu **Logcat** o seguinte erro ao tentar instalar o aplicativo, caso tenha oportunidade de testar em um aparelho com *Lollipop*:

> Error -505 while installing :
>   INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package  attempting to
>   redeclare permission .permission.C2D_MESSAGE already owned by...

Comment: e no caso de `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` tenho que mudar também? Muitos apps usam o mesmo nome de pacotes.

Tentei mudar o nome daquele pacote, mas ainda dá erro, talvez por causa dos outros pacotes como o INTERNET.

Isto é um bug do 5.0, ou é algo definitivo do Lollipop?
Será que nas versões 5.1 e 5.2 está arrumado isto?

Para resolver vou ter que mudar o nome do pacote até mesmo do internet?

Comment: Esse caso não se aplica. O erro se refere à duplicidade de **permissão assinada**, que no caso é do *C2D_MESSAGE*. Por exemplo, outro caso que se aplicaria é o *MAPS_RECEIVE*, que também necessita de uma permissão assinada.